# Angular2 typescript set selected dropdown button value on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typescript, angular

Ref : trying to use Dropdown component https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/dropdown

I can pull the drop down values on clicking button and persist on selection using Typescript but **couldn't set the selected value on page load** like we do using select option like :

```
<option [selected]="value.id == value.statusId">
```

Parent template :

```
 <dropdownst [values]="releaseNames" [selectedReleaseId]="item.releaseId"></dropdownst>
```

Object : releaseName.ts

```
export class ReleaseName {
releaseId: number;
name: string;
}
```

Dropdown Component :

```
@Component({
selector: 'dropdownst',
template: `<div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" (click)="dropdownMenu($event)">
                        RELEASE (Toggle)
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" dropdown [(isOpen)]="status.isopen">
                <button id="dropdown-list" class="btn btn-default" dropdownToggle >
                        {{title}} 
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-list">
                    <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let data of values">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" [id]="data.releaseId"  #val [title]="data.name" 
                              (click)="updatePbiRelease(val.id, val.title)" >
                                    {{data.name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div> `,
directives: [ DropdownDirective, DropdownMenuDirective, DropdownToggleDirective, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
styles:['.scrollable-menu {height: auto;max-height: 200px;overflow-x: hidden;}']
 })
export class Angular2Dropdown implements OnInit{
@Input()
selectedReleaseId: number;
@Input()
values: ReleaseName[];
@Input()
title: string;
private disabledMenu:boolean = false;
appComponent: AppComponent;
private status:{isopen:boolean} = {isopen: false};

constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) private _parent:AppComponent){
    this.appComponent = _parent;
    }

updatePbiRelease(releaseValue, title){
    this.appComponent.updatePbiRelease(releaseValue);
    this.title = title;
    }
private dropdownMenu($event:MouseEvent):void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.status.isopen = !this.status.isopen;
    }
ngOnInit() {     
    }    
}
```

Html Template :

```
<div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
    <div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" (click)="dropdownMenu($event)">
                        RELEASE (Toggle)
       </button>
    </div>
 <div class="btn-group" dropdown [(isOpen)]="status.isopen">
       <button id="dropdown-list" class="btn btn-default" dropdownToggle >

//Trying to set dropdown selected value here on page load as title from DB on TS  Angular 2
                        {{title}} 

         <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-list">

//Iterate through releaseName has values passed from parent template 
//to get name (i.e title) matchng releaseId and Id from DB(i.e item.releaseId)
       <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let data of values">
         <a class="dropdown-item" [id]="data.releaseId"  #val [title]="data.releaseId == selectedReleaseId ? data.name : data.name" 
          (click)="updatePbiRelease(val.id, val.title)" >
                {{data.name}}
         </a>
       </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is this `[(isOpen)]`?

Comment: Its method in https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/dropdown/dropdown.directive.ts comes with the component for triggering dropdown event value

Comment: I see how they did it. OK. I think you have to try binding like [(NgModel)]="title" not like {{title}}.

Comment: I will try on ngModel..

Comment: I tried on different ways setting title like <a [id]="data.releaseId" #val [title]="data.releaseId == id ? data.name : data.name" [(ngModel)]="title" (click)="updatePbiRelease(val.id, val.title)" >{{data.name}}</a> but throws ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' can you please correct the syntax

Comment: @Mate  If i use [(ngModel)] or [ngModel] it throws ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' please help on checking my code

Comment: OK. At first change also `#data` to `let data`, because this first option is deprecated. If I understood you properly, you want to set `title` from the beginning. `title` is connected with those `li`s and you have just one such variable in controller. So this `[(NgModel)]` should be on `ul` level if so. Also I don't see all of your code. Are you getting this title` from somewhere? Or you just want to set it always to known value? If 2nd then you can set it in the constructor.

Comment: From "let data of values" values is array of  ReleaseName which has releaseId and name(i.e name is title). If the ReleaseName entity is already in database on page load it should be already selected in dropdown if user has to change he can change and persist. So now i have only  releaseId for dropdown  and array of ReleaseName so i have to iterate and compare releaseId and get title(i.e name in ReleaseName) like [title]="data.releaseId == selectedReleaseId ? data.name : data.name".

Comment: @Mate .. title is local variable of that component. Is there global variable to set and get that value in top element outside of that iteration... thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the following changes to Template and ngOnInit() to work

Template :

```
template: `<div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" (click)="dropdownMenu($event)">
                        RELEASE (Toggle)
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" dropdown [(isOpen)]="status.isopen">
                <button id="dropdown-list" class="btn btn-default" dropdownToggle >
                        {{title}} 
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-list">
                    <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let data of values">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" [id]="data.releaseId"  #val [title]="data.name" 
                              (click)="updatePbiRelease(val.id, val.title)" >
                                    {{data.name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div> `,
```

Added a if condition on releaseName on parent template

```
<dropdown *ngIf="releaseNames" [values]="releaseNames" [selectedReleaseId]="item.releaseId">
```

Set the title value on **page load onInit** using the id passed from parent template selectedReleaseId

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.values.length; x++) {
        if(this.values[x].releaseId == this.selectedReleaseId) {
            this.title = this.values[x].name;
        }
    }     
 }
```